# How to mention fully classified class name in glue attribute in Cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

I am new in Cucumber and created one sample application 
Here is the folder structure of it[Cucumber folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEz7a.png)

My test runner class code is

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)    
@CucumberOptions(features = "Feature/SampleTest.feature",     
                 glue = { "com.testSteps.Test_Steps" })
public class TestRunner {

}
```

Now my step definition class is `Test_Steps` but if I mention that class in glue attribute i.e. `glue = { "com.testSteps.Test_Steps" }` then test runner is not able to find the test definition class. Below console output I am getting

```
You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Given("^User is on Home Page$")
public void user_is_on_Home_Page() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

Please help me define step definition class with glue attribute because in case I have multiple step definition classes in my step definition folder structure then how can I target particular step definition class in glue attribute?

Answer (score 3):

The `glue` parameter in your `@CucumberOptions` must point to a package, not a class. So in your case:

```
glue = {"com.testSteps.", "", ...}
```

And you `features` parameter should point to a folder with all the feature files. It can have subdirectories as well.

Comment: Thank You for the answer , I appreciate that. I have 2 step definition classes in my "com.testSteps" package . So how can I target particular step definition class which has made for feature file.

Comment: @Ufaq You can only target a whole folder. If you need to point only on specific features, place them in a separate folder.